# Dynamically append child from directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a basic element:

```
<div>
    I'm a basic element
</div>
```

I want to create a directive that allows me to write this:

```
<div resizable-top>
    I'm a basic element
</div>
```

and renders this:

```
<div resizable-top>
    <div> drag me to resize element </div>
    I'm a basic element
</div>
```

So, basically I made a directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[resizable-top]',
    host: {
        '(mousedown)':'onMouseDown()',
        '(mousemove)':'onMouseMove()',
        '(mouseover)':'onMouseOver()'
    }
})
export class ResizableDirective{

    constructor(private el:ElementRef){
    }

    onMouseDown(){
        //TODO
    }

    onMouseMove(){
        //TODO
    }

    onMouseOver(){
        //TODO
    }
}
```

problem is that I don't know how to create a child element using `el` and I want the events to be binded on child element, not on the actual element.

Since `ElementRef.nativeElement` is of type `any` I can't find out which methods/properties I can use to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`el.nativeElement` returns a [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) if the selector contains a `-` otherwise an [HtmlUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement)

The Angular way of doing it is to use the [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html) class in combination with `ElementRef` anyway.

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer){
}
```

and use the method it provides.

This keeps your application WebWorker and server-side-rendering safe.

Comment: Renderer is really usefull, but creating an element is appending the ellement to the view, is there a way to prepend it instead?

Comment: Prepend in relation to what? Prepend to `el`? For this you would need something like `el.nativeElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newChild, el.nativeElement)`. I don't think this can be done with the renderer.

Comment: I mean that if I have `<div resizable-top><div class="child"></div></div>` I want to append my new element in first div, before child:  `<div resizable-top><div>Here</div><div class="child"></div></div>` instead of after child.

Comment: I guess in this case you still need `insertBefore()` but you can use `<div resizable-top><div #firstChild>Here</div><div class="child"></div></div>` with `@ViewChild() firstChild` and then `this._el.nativeElement.insertBefore(newElement, this.firstChild.nativeElement)`. `firstChild` will not be available in the constructor, only after when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called.